# CCScrollLayer doesn't scroll when touch begins from the CCMenuItem position

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm working with cocos2d and managed to make CCScrollLayer work horizontally and vertically. Then I add (quite big) CCMenuItemImage/Sprite to CCLayer and then pass CCLayers to the scrolling layer. It works fine but the problem is that CCScrollLayer doesn't read any touched when I start moving my finger from position of any CCMenuItem so I cannot scroll my view in the intuitive way. How can I solve this? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

When i use the `CCScrollLayer`, i am adding the `CCMENU` on the layers, and then, the layers to the `CCScrollLayer` like that :

```
CCLayer *page1 = [[CCLayer alloc] init];
```

then some menu :

```
Menu= [CCMenu menuWithItems: item1, nil];
```

then the menu on the layer :

```
 [page1 addChild:Menu z:0 ];
```

then the layer to the scroller :

```
scroller = [[CCScrollLayer alloc] initWithLayers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:page1,page2,page3,nil] widthOffset:0];
```

so you can add many pages like that with menus .

and it do works great .
hope it helped .

Comment: thanks for the answer and I'm doing it in the same way but it doesn't work in the way I want it to work. Make your CCMenuItem big like 70% width of the screen and 90% height of the screen and then place your finger on top of the element and try to scroll the layer, it won't work. in order to scroll ccScrollLayer you have to start scrolling from the position that id free from menu item :). Now I'm trying to integrated UIkit with UIScrollView and UIButtons with occos2d because I know it will work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
CCLayer *pageSeventhScroll = [[CCLayer alloc] init];
CCSprite * bgDonts= [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"donts~ipad.jpg"];
bgDonts.tag = 102;
bgDonts.position=CGPointMake(512,384);
[pageSeventhScroll addChild:bgDonts];
currentBackground = bgDonts;
CCScrollLayer *scroller = [[CCScrollLayer alloc] initWithLayers:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: pageSeventhScroll,nil] widthOffset: 0];

// finally add the scroller to your scene
[self addChild:scroller];
```